# Prove C(A) is a subspace of a linear mapping from $R^n$ to $R^m$

Tags: linear-algebra

The exercise is the following:

> The column space $C(A)$ of a linear mapping $A : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is defined by
>
> $$C(A)=\{y ∈ R^n |∃ x ∈ \mathbb{R}^m\text{ with }y=Ax\}$$
>
> Prove that $C(A)$ is a subspace of $R^n$ .

I'm a little confused, say it's a mapping from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, what does it mean this mapping for my column space? Am I making all the vector become a plane after applying the transformation $A$? I would like to understand what is actually happening before I can understand how I prove it to be true.

Comment: I am confused. Which new mapping? Is there some old mapping here?

Comment: i corrected my question, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a linear transformation $T:V\rightarrow W$ between finite dimensional vector spaces $V$ and $W$ over the same field $\textbf{F}$. The problem asks us to prove that $T(V)\subseteq W$ is a linear subspace. Indeed, this is the case.

In order to prove it, let us consider that $w_{1}$ and $w_{2}$ belong to $T(V)$. Given $a\in\textbf{F}$, we must prove that $aw_{1} + w_{2}$ also belongs to $T(V)$.

But, if $w_{1}\in T(V)$, there exists $v_{1}\in V$ such that $T(v_{1}) = w_{1}$. Similarly, if $w_{2}\in T(V)$, there exists $v_{2}\in V$ such that $T(v_{2}) = w_{2}$. Since $av_{1} + v_{2} \in V$, it is true that $T(av_{1} + v_{2})\in T(V)$, which implies that
\begin{align*}
T(av_{1} + v_{2}) \in T(V) \Longrightarrow aT(v_{1}) + T(v_{2}) \in T(V) \Longrightarrow aw_{1} + w_{2} \in T(V)
\end{align*}
just as desired. Hence $T(V)$ is a linear subspace of $W$.

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you has a linear map $A$ from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ (think about it as a $m \times n$ matrix with real entries). Then, the *column space* of $A$ is the set of all column vectors $y$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ that can be written as $Ax$, for some column vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ (observe that, the matrix multiplication is well-defined).

For example, if $A : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is given by the matrix
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1&3&2 \\ 1&4&1 \end{pmatrix}$$
then the columns of the matrix,
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 3\\4 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 2\\1 \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^2$$
are in the column space of $A$ since they can be written as
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1\\1 \end{pmatrix} = A \begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix}, 
\begin{pmatrix} 3\\4 \end{pmatrix} = A \begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix},
\textrm{ and}$$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 2\\1 \end{pmatrix} = A \begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\1 \end{pmatrix}.$$